# os.path.abspath() returning different results for same file

Tags: python, macos, os.path

I am getting a different result for a file in `os.path.abspath()` when it is run in a unit test versus when it is run in the code being tested:

The code I am testing contains:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(filepath)
```

My test for the code copies the file into the test directory and executes the code

```
self.test_data = os.path.dirname(test_data.__file__)
self.test_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="test_")
shutil.copy(
    os.path.join(self.test_data, "thefile.txt"),
    os.path.join(self.test_dir, "thefile.txt"),
)
```

When the test is executed it fails. The code being tested produces this as the path for the test file:

`/private/var/folders/1w/k19bxrj1463_4j5m8xv6_6cc0000gp/T/test_z66pgwj_/thefile.txt`

but the test expects the path to be:

`/var/folders/1w/k19bxrj1463_4j5m8xv6_6cc0000gp/T/test_z66pgwj_/thefile.txt`

When I run `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.test_dir, thefile.txt))` in the test it returns the same path without `/private` prepended.

I am using python 3.9.13 running on MacOS Monterey 12.6.2

EDIT:  I have solved the issue, but the solution makes no sense to me:

`os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.test_dir, "thefile.txt"))` returns:

`/var/folders/1w/k19bxrj1463_4j5m8xv6_6cc0000gp/T/test_z66pgwj_/thefile.txt`

`os.path.abspath("thefile.txt)` returns:

`/private/var/folders/1w/k19bxrj1463_4j5m8xv6_6cc0000gp/T/test_z66pgwj_/thefile.txt`

Comment: Can you clarify what the confusion is? You didn't call `abspath` in the `shutil.copy` call. Are you asking why `abspath('/private/var/...')` returns `'/var/...'`?

Comment: ```os.path.abspath``` run in the test returns the path without ```/private``` prepended when it is run in the code it prepends ```/private```.

Comment: Just looking at the last few lines looks like the difference might be running in a VM or virtual environment.  Possibly you're running it with different Python installs? Without using Python or the test suite, check to see which of the two paths are present on your disk.  Just dig around with `ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.path.abspath()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/posixpath.py#L397) works with paths as common strings, it doesn't even check for path to exist.  And `/var/` and `/tmp/` are symlinks on macOS:

```sh
 % ls -lh /tmp /var
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 Jan 11 11:03 /tmp -> private/tmp
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 Jan 11 11:03 /var -> private/var
```

Therefore there's a bunch of tools returning unexpected (at first glance) results:

```sh
 % cd /tmp && touch "file.txt" && readlink -f file.txt

/private/tmp/file.txt
```

`os.path.abspath(path)` checks if `path` starts with `/`.  If not, it calls `os.getcwd()` to get current dir, which on macOS returns the one with `/private` prefix.  If `path` starts with `/`, `os.getcwd()` isn't called, and `abspath()` proceeds to normalize path string.